# What is the difference between javascript require("file") vs require("file.js")?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, module

I have two files.

- import.js
- export.js

In import I do:

```js
const export = require('export')
```

This will successful import the module from export.js. When I do `require('export.js')` (with file ending) it is also working.

So I was wondering what is the difference there? Is without slower?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js automatically resolves some extensions. For example: .js, .json, etc. No, it works the same with or without the extension.

Comment: Is there a specific order of file extensions NodeJS tries out? What if there are two files with same name?

Comment: It's not possible to have two files with same name inside a same the location.

Comment: It's quite possible if files have different extensions. I'm not sure about the order. But by the common sense, it should try the .js extension first.

Answer (score 0):

`require` in `Node.js` takes one argument which can be either module name or path. You can [read](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together) for more info.

Comment: You have pointed to the proper spot in the documentation, but this will be a useful answer if you include the steps described there. `LOAD_AS_FILE(X)`

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `import/export` and `require` is that `require` uses `commonjs` under the hood. While the `import` was introduced in ES6.

Even if you use ES6 `import` it's still transpiled into the`commonjs`. But using ES6 is recommended because with the time, it will be widely supported.

Performance-wise the difference will be negligible because the module files are evaluated only once but you will have to benchmark it, if you are very keen on the performance.